# PHP post values limit, suggestions needed to limit my posts

Tags: php, post

I'm building a page for an php/mysql eshop in which i display a list of all products with textbox for price[], another one for special_offer_price[] and a checkbox (homepage[]) next to each to select the products to be displayed on the home page. This page is for batch updating prices so that the store owner can update prices for all products by using a single page instead of going into each product one by one.

The problem is that the store has about 500 products so I'm posting 500x4=2000 post values to the page that updates the products. My PHP limit for posts is 1000 values, is there a better way I can use to limit my posts?

Comment: is paging the list of products an option, so that you only have like 100 products per page only?

Comment: Could do but i'd prefer not to.

Comment: you could also use javascript to only post ones that have changed.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. What should I look for? Maybe a small portion of code would help me get on track.

Comment: ..or you could split the one big form into several smaller ones (e.g. with 500 entries each). That would be like pagination - but on one page :-D

Answer (score 1):

As for using javascript to send only modified data:

Step 1: emit original values

```
<input type="hidden" id="price1_original" value="3.5" />
<input type="text" id="price1" class="price" value="3.5" />
```

Step 2: in form submit handler, select only changed ones

```
changed = $('.price').filter(function() {
  var original = $('#' + this.id + '_original').val();
  return this.val() != original;
});
```

Step 3: prepare and send AJAX request

```
$.post('/change_price.php', {prices : data}, function(response) {
  // handle response
});
```

Step 4: PROFIT! :-)

UPD: Yet another solution would be to send changes right away, when user changed a value and moved focus elsewhere.

```
$('.price').change(function() {
  // validate input
  // post this single price change to server
});
```

Comment: One can always use a hidden input for that :-) Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to display all records on the same page. Break that product list in pages and display (for example) up to 50 products per page. Provide navigation to first/prev/next/last page and so on.

You can combine this with text filtering.

This way you have predictable performance and behaviour of the system.

Comment: As above, I prefer not to, not that I dont see your point but I'd like to stick with the original concept if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to show all products at once, you could create the inputs dynamically when needed via javascript. Your data could e.g. be shown in a `<div>` which has a click handler attached; and when the user clicks that div, the div is transformed to an input. That way, you'd only even have to transmit those fields which were modified! And you could count how many inputs there are and limit that number to your PHP post limit...

Comment: That's a good one. However, in hypothetical case of mass reassignment it is annoying to click on every div when you could just tab through them.